# compile warning: uses unchecked or unsafe operations

Tags: java

When I want to build a jar file using artifacts I get the following error:

> Warning:java: Note:
>   /Users/doekewartena/IdeaProjects/LemmingsWalker/Java-Base/src/com/github/lemmingswalker/ListDivisor.java
>   uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Warning:java: Note: Recompile
>   with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

I still get a jar file but I have problems in another project which I think are related to this.
I have seen solutions on stackoverflow. Most of the times people seem to use `new ArrayList()` instead of `new ArrayList<TheType>()`. In my case, it might be something similar, but I can't finds it. I hope someone can.

```
public class ListDivisor<T> {

    List<T> list;

    int subListStartIndex = 0;
    int currentGetIndex = 0;

    InstanceHelper instanceHelper;


    public ListDivisor(List<T> list, InstanceHelper<T> instanceHelper) {
        this.list = list;
        this.instanceHelper = instanceHelper;
    }

    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .


    public void reset() {
        subListStartIndex = 0;
        currentGetIndex = 0;

        if (instanceHelper.doResetInstances()) {
            for (T obj : list) {
                instanceHelper.resetInstance(obj);
            }
        }
    }

    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .


    public SubListGetter<T> getSubListGetter(int size) {

        int fromIndex = subListStartIndex; // inclusive
        int toIndex = fromIndex + size; // exclusive

        for (int i = list.size(); i < toIndex; i++) {
            list.add((T) instanceHelper.createInstance());
        }

        subListStartIndex = toIndex;
        currentGetIndex = toIndex;

        //return list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
        return new SubListGetter(fromIndex, toIndex, list);
    }

    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

    /**
     * Returns a subList starting where the previous subList ended till
     * the latest object added till then.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public SubListGetter<T> getSubListGetter() {
        return getSubListGetter(currentGetIndex - subListStartIndex);
    }

    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .


    public T getNext() {

        if (currentGetIndex >= list.size()) {
           list.add((T)instanceHelper.createInstance());
        }

        return list.get(currentGetIndex++);

    }

    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .


    public void clear() {
        list.clear();
        reset();
    }


    // =====================================================================

    public interface InstanceHelper<T> {
        public T createInstance();
        public boolean doResetInstances();
        public void resetInstance(T obj);
    }

    // =====================================================================


}
```

And the SubListGetter class:

```
public class SubListGetter<T> {

    int fromIndex, toIndex;
    List<T> target;

    public SubListGetter (int fromIndex, int toIndex, List<T> target) {
        this.fromIndex = fromIndex;
        this.toIndex = toIndex;
        this.target = target;
    }

    public List<T> getSubList() {
        return target.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens when you recompile with -Xlint:unchecked as it suggests?

Comment: If the code compiles successfully the messages have no effect on the generated program.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I did that but it does not seem to affect the artifact build. I setted it in (intelliJ) File > Settings > Default Settings > Compiler > Java Compiler > Additional Command Line Parameters

Comment: @HotLicks I'm afraid your right :(

Comment: It shouldn't affect the artifact, but, as the warning message states, it should give more detail. You may need to run it from the command line rather than from within an IDE (although intellij should show whatever message the compiler returns).

Comment: I fixed the other problem. One jar file was not included for the ant build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field `instanceHelper` is a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) of `InstanceHelper`. You should use the type parameter `T`:

```
InstanceHelper<T> instanceHelper;
```

You can remove the casting to `T` once that's complete:

```
for (int i = list.size(); i < toIndex; i++) {
   list.add(instanceHelper.createInstance());
}
```